# How to fix the error of Failed building wheel for mysqlclient in flask

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I have a problem in installing the mysql-python package for flask.

I had tried using the command:
pip install mysql-python
But i did'nt workout for me

Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\yuvan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Yuvan\AppData\Local\Temp\
\pip-install-c23xj5e_\mysql-python\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install -
-record C:\Users\Yuvan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7h3c9v2a\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
Git
GitHub
Initialize E:\chakra with a Git repository
Create repository

I  expect that this package would be installed successfully

Answer (score 1):

You can install `mysqlclient` for python using the following command :

> `pip install mysqlclient`

And If you are looking for particular version :

> `pip install mysqlclient==<verison>` (e.g. version -> 1.3.6)